# Setting data attribute to button and chainging the value of said attr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a0qqkgdL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn1', function (e) {
        var qwe = $(this).data('id');
        var asd = $(this).data('table');
        console.log(qwe);
        $('#btn2').attr('data-id', qwe);
        $('#btn2').click();

    });
    $("#btn2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var q = $(this).data('id');
        var a = $(this).data('table');
        console.log(q);
        func1(q, a);
    });
});

function func1(data, value) {
    $('#text').val(data);
}
```

I have here 3 buttons; namely btn1,btn1.1,btn2. btn1 and btn1.1 share the same class btn1 I have a click event on class btn1. On btn1 click event I get the btn's `data-id` using `$(this).data('id');` then i set it that same attr in btn2 like this `$('#btn2').attr('data-id', qwe);`. On click of btn2 I run a function that sets the value of an input.

My problem is like this, when I click on btn1 the data-id is passed onto btn2 I can see that it  changes in dev tools. When I click again in btn1.1 the data-id is still passed onto btn2 in dev tools but it does not change in the input val.

Why is this happening. How to fix this?

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a0qqkgdL/2/)**

Updated fiddle checking for click event in btn2

Comment: Are you sure the btn2 click event is being called? If it is not calling then try to replace `$('#btn2').click()` with `$('#btn2').trigger('click')`

Comment: yes it is clicked check http://jsfiddle.net/a0qqkgdL/2/

Comment: @Gagan `$('#btn2').click()` and `$('#btn2').trigger('click')` is same. Check https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @Pekka The answer below is correct. Alternatively, you can send extra parameters when triggering event, Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a0qqkgdL/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/a0qqkgdL/3/)**

Set value using the following using [**`data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) itself.

```
$('#btn2').data('id', qwe);
```

You cannot use [**`attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for setting `data` because `data-id` is not a valid attribute for an element.

But if you use [**`prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [**`attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) it will work.

```
$('#btn2').prop('data-id', qwe);
```

Comment: can you explain what is the difference in setting data like `$('#btn2').attr('data-id', qwe);` and `$('#btn2').data('id', qwe);` also what is happening i just want to understand. your answer works

Comment: @Pekka You cannot use attr() for setting data because data-id is not a valid attribute for an element.

But if you use prop() instead of attr() it will work.

Comment: i see give me a few minutes to tick the answer explanation is great. happy coding

Comment: @Pekka happy to help. Happy coding.

Comment: neighther `$('#btn2').data('id', qwe);` nor `$('#btn2').prop('data-id', qwe);`   worked at all for me.  Now I use `attr('data-my_data',value)`

Comment: When you set `$('#btn2').data('id', qwe);` you should read it using `$('#btn2').data('id');` or `$('#btn2').prop('data-id');`.

Answer (score 0):

Now please have a run the below Snippet and you can reduce delay time once you're able to see the Btn2 data value updated.

Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn1', function (e) {
        var qwe = $(this).data('id');
        var asd = $(this).data('table');
        
        $('#btn2').attr('data-id', qwe);
        
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#btn2').click();
        }, 2000); 
    });
  
    $("#btn2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var q = $(this).data('id');
        var a = $(this).data('table');
        func1(q, a);
    });
});

function func1(data, value) {
    $('#text').val(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Btn 1" data-table="btn 1 table val" data-id="btn 1 id val" class="btn1" />
<input type="button" value="Btn 2" id="btn2" />
<input type="text" value="" size="50" id="text" />
```

Comment: Please have a look the demo and let me know any more help needed. thanks!